# logs are not sent to the aggregator server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fluentd, aws-elasticsearch

I have 2 ec2 instance
first instance in availability zone a, secon in in availability zone b
first instance must forward logs to second, but i have an error

```
2022-01-10 20:15:42 +0000 [warn]: detached forwarding server '3.12.161.218:24224' host="3.12.161.218" port=24224 phi=16.01073005960133
```

3.12.161.218 - public ip
i tried private ip in config

```
2022-01-10 20:20:25 +0000 [warn]: detached forwarding server '172.31.13.116:24224' host="172.31.13.116" port=24224 phi=16.39846510698621
```

but it still doesn't work

my config first instance(forwader):

```
<match td.*.*>
  @type tdlog
  apikey YOUR_API_KEY
  auto_create_table
  buffer_type file
  buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/buffer/td

  <secondary>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/failed_records
  </secondary>
</match>

## match tag=debug.** and dump to console
<match debug.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

## built-in TCP input
## @see http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_forward

<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<source>
  @type http
  port 8888
</source>

## live debugging agent

<source>
  @type debug_agent
  bind 127.0.0.1
  port 24230
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/myapp.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/myorg.log.pos
  tag myorg.myapp
  format /^(?<level>[^ ]*)[ \t]+\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<request>[^\]]*)\] (?<class>[^ ]*): (?<message>.*)$/

  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L %z
  timezone +0530
  time_key time
  keep_time_key true
  types time:time
</source>

<match myorg.**>
   @type copy
   <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/forward.log
  </store>

  <store>
    @type forward
    heartbeat_type tcp

    #aggregator IP
    host 172.31.13.116
    flush_interval 30s
  </store>

</match>
```

there are also problems with the aggregator, which must transfer data to the aws elastic search cloud
config aggregator:

```
<source>
  @type forward
   port 24224
</source>

<match myorg.**>
  @type copy
    <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/forward.log
  </store>

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch_dynamic
    #elasticsearch host IP/domain
    host ec2-3-13-147-36.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    port 9200
    index_name fluentd-${tag_parts[1]+ "-" + Time.at(time).getlocal("+05:30").strftime(@logstash_dateformat)}

    #logstash_format true
    #logstash_prefix fluentd

    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
    #timezone +0530
    include_timestamp true

    flush_interval 10s
  </store>
</match>
```

I don't understand how to make a connection so that everything works correctly

Comment: Looks like the `tag` is missing in `source` to route the events. See https://docs.fluentd.org/input/forward#tag. For example, in the aggregator, add `tag myorg.**` under `source` and then test that. Also, this would be helpful: https://docs.fluentd.org/quickstart/life-of-a-fluentd-event.

Comment: Can you enable debugging of td-agent? Also, have you opened port 24224 on instance b? try connection first by doing a telnet from server a to be on port 24224.